# Prometheus remote read write URL 404 not found

Tags: prometheus, open-telemetry, thanos

I configured OpenTelemetry in Kubernetes. I want to monitor OpenTelemetry metrics using Prometheus. For that I installed Thanos such that Prometheus Remote Write Exporter will send OpenTelemtry metrics to Thanos.

I installed Thanos using Helm command. Below are the objects.

```
NAME                                        READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/thanos-query-776688f499-pvm24           1/1     Running   0          14h
pod/thanos-query-frontend-5b55d44cc-b6qx5   1/1     Running   0          14h

NAME                            TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)              AGE
service/thanos-query            ClusterIP   10.0.112.105   <none>        9090/TCP,10901/TCP   14h
service/thanos-query-frontend   ClusterIP   10.0.223.246   <none>        9090/TCP             14h

NAME                                    READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/thanos-query            1/1     1            1           14h
deployment.apps/thanos-query-frontend   1/1     1            1           14h

NAME                                              DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/thanos-query-776688f499           1         1         1       14h
replicaset.apps/thanos-query-frontend-5b55d44cc   1         1         1       14h
```

After that I configured the below URL in OpenTelemtry

```
exporters:
  prometheusremotewrite:
    endpoint: "http://thanos-query-frontend.thanos:9090/api/v1/write"
```

But the OpenTelemetry pod logs shows 404

```
2022-06-07T07:31:19.739Z        error   exporterhelper/queued_retry.go:183      Exporting failed. The error is not retryable. Dropping data.    {"kind": "exporter", "name": "prometheusremotewrite", "error": "Permanent error: Permanent error: remote write returned HTTP status 404 Not Found; err = <nil>: 404 page not found\n", "dropped_items": 29}
go.opentelemetry.io/collector/exporter/exporterhelper.(*retrySender).send
        go.opentelemetry.io/collector@v0.51.0/exporter/exporterhelper/queued_retry.go:183
go.opentelemetry.io/collector/exporter/exporterhelper.(*metricsSenderWithObservability).send
        go.opentelemetry.io/collector@v0.51.0/exporter/exporterhelper/metrics.go:132
go.opentelemetry.io/collector/exporter/exporterhelper.(*queuedRetrySender).start.func1
        go.opentelemetry.io/collector@v0.51.0/exporter/exporterhelper/queued_retry_inmemory.go:118
go.opentelemetry.io/collector/exporter/exporterhelper/internal.consumerFunc.consume
        go.opentelemetry.io/collector@v0.51.0/exporter/exporterhelper/internal/bounded_memory_queue.go:82
go.opentelemetry.io/collector/exporter/exporterhelper/internal.(*boundedMemoryQueue).StartConsumers.func2
        go.opentelemetry.io/collector@v0.51.0/exporter/exporterhelper/internal/bounded_memory_queue.go:69
```

*****InfluxDB*****

```
2022-06-08T17:03:03.902Z        error   exporterhelper/queued_retry.go:183      Exporting failed. The error is not retryable. Dropping data.    {"kind": "exporter", "name": "prometheusremotewrite", "error": "Permanent error: Permanent error: remote write returned HTTP status 404 Not Found; err = <nil>: 404 page not found\n", "dropped_items": 27}
go.opentelemetry.io/collector/exporter/exporterhelper.(*retrySender).send
        go.opentelemetry.io/collector@v0.51.0/exporter/exporterhelper/queued_retry.go:183
go.opentelemetry.io/collector/exporter/exporterhelper.(*metricsSenderWithObservability).send
        go.opentelemetry.io/collector@v0.51.0/exporter/exporterhelper/metrics.go:132
go.opentelemetry.io/collector/exporter/exporterhelper.(*queuedRetrySender).start.func1
        go.opentelemetry.io/collector@v0.51.0/exporter/exporterhelper/queued_retry_inmemory.go:118
go.opentelemetry.io/collector/exporter/exporterhelper/internal.consumerFunc.consume
        go.opentelemetry.io/collector@v0.51.0/exporter/exporterhelper/internal/bounded_memory_queue.go:82
go.opentelemetry.io/collector/exporter/exporterhelper/internal.(*boundedMemoryQueue).StartConsumers.func2
        go.opentelemetry.io/collector@v0.51.0/exporter/exporterhelper/internal/bounded_memory_queue.go:69
```

Answer (score 1):

https://thanos.io/tip/components/receive.md/

So I guess correct endpoint is `/api/v1/receive`, so use:

```
exporters:
  prometheusremotewrite:
    endpoint: "http://thanos-query-frontend.thanos:9090/api/v1/receive"
```

Comment: Same error with 404. In Thanos do I need to do any config change?

Comment: @Container-Man check Thanos doc and your Thanos deployment - are you sure that "query-frontend" is that component which support remote write? I don't think - https://thanos.io/tip/thanos/quick-tutorial.md/#components You need to point it to the Thanos Receiver, not to Thanos Query Frontend.

Comment: I installed InfluxDB endpoint and it's also the same. I added content above